# Electron Build Windows Folder Structure

Tags: electron

Given an application made in electron. The folder structure would look something like:

```
App
  - assets
    -models
      - exe files
index.html
main.js
```

When executing the build following the recommendation of the site by entering the following command:

```
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="Electron Tutorial App"
```

The electron v.1.7.9 creates the build correctly, however it inside the release-builds / resources folder the app.asar file, so all the content that was inside my models folder becomes inaccessible. Inside this folder were .exe files that should be run on demand.

The system then looks for the files in the following url: parth_do_projeto / resources / app.asar / assets / models /, that is, it considers that the app.assar is a folder, but after the app.asar build is a file.

Since there were .exe files inside the original folder, the app.asar can not absorb executables.

What would be the way I keep these .exe files? If you build the build without the --asar parameter, the program works correctly, enter, all my project folder / source code is exposed.

My question is what is the best way to generate the build, keeping the code closed and making use of .exe files?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is to use the `unpackDir` option for the asar option inside of electron-packager.  Here is a sample of what this might look like:

```
'use strict';
...   ...
var packager = require('electron-packager');
var electronPackage = require('electron/package.json');
var pkg = require('./package.json');
// pull the electron version from the package.json file
var electronVersion = electronPackage.version;
...   ...

var opts = {
    name: pkg.name,
    platform: 'win32',
    arch: 'ia32',                           // ia32, x64 or all
    dir: './',                       // source location of app
    out: './edist/',              // destination location for app os/native binaries
    ignore: config.electronignore,          // don't include these directories in the electron app build
    icon: config.icon,
    asar: {unpackDir: config.excludeFromASAR}, // compress project/modules into an asar blob excluding some things.
    overwrite: true,
    prune: true,
    electronVersion: electronVersion ,       // Tell the packager what version of electron to build with
    appCopyright: pkg.copyright,            // copyright info
    appVersion: pkg.version,         // The version of the application we are building
    win32metadata: {                        // Windows Only config data
        CompanyName: pkg.authors,
        ProductName: pkg.name,
        FileDescription: pkg.description,
        OriginalFilename: pkg.name + '.exe'
    }
};


// Build the electron app
gulp.task('build:electron', function (cb) {

    console.log('Launching task to package binaries for ' + opts.name + ' v' + opts['appVersion']);

    packager(opts, function (err, appPath) {
        console.log(' <- packagerDone() ' + err + ' ' + appPath);
        console.log(' all done!');
        cb();
    });
});
```